# Declaration of a complex C expression

Tags: ida, c, functions

I used IDA Pro and got the following expression from a produced C file:

```
v25 = (*(int (**)(void))(v22 + 464))();
```

I am trying to figure out the meaning of the above expression with the following links:

http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations

I start with `(v22 + 464)` and then go out of the parenthesis and to the left to the following `*(int (**)(void))`.

But, still can't understand. Any hints?

EDIT: I guess this expression is not a declaration but a function call.

(v22+464) is then cast to a pointer to a pointer to a function that takes void as an argument and returns an int. Then that pointer is dereference and the () operator is applied - the function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(*(int (**)(void))(v22 + 464))()` is a function call (`v22` is an object (perhaps a vtable) that contains a function pointer).